# slow down of mpi by Torque

Tags: mpi, torque

I'm running Torque with Open MPI on a cluster with 30 nodes and 360 cores. 
I have found that the wall time of 
     `mpirun -np N ~./myjob`
and 
     `qsub -l nodes=1:ppn=N mpirun -np N ~./myjob`
differs many times. For  small jobs it grows from 1.2 s to 20 s, from 2 s to 37 s  and so on.
For larger jobs the difference becomes important. How to overcome it?

Comment: The clustering software is GridEngine? I'm assuming this based on the command `qsub ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it depends on the stuffing of `./myjob`.  If this script includes the creation and reading of files then they are created *N* times and their reading causes interference.  The slow down is absent if `./myjob` is just binary, then the execution time is more or less the same.